Mathematics Fun Puzzle for Shortest Distance Between Cells

The conditions are as follows:
The “Manhattan distance” between two cells is the shortest distance between those
cells when traveling up, down, left, or right, as if one were traveling along city blocks rather
than as the crow flies.
Place numbers from 1-6 in some cells so the following criteria are satisfied:

A cell contains at most one number. Cells can be left empty.
For each cell containing a number N in the grid, exactly two other cells containing N
are at a Manhattan distance of N.
For each cell containing a number N in the grid, no other cells containing N are at a
Manhattan distance less than N.

My work so far is as follows:

How Can I change it so I satisfy the conditions for the 4 and the 5?
Thank you!

The grid you want to solve:

If I had solve this problem, I would first find that the cells that contain a 6. On the following grid, the grey cells cannot contain a 6:

Moreover, there should be (at least) two 6s to fill the second criterion. Combining with your third constraint, there is only one way to do so. We fill the grid accordingly, and color in grey the cells that cannot contain a 5:

By the same argument, we must fill these two cells with 5s. Now for the 4s, it is a bit trickier. First, color in grey the cells that can't contain a 4:

Three of those cells cannot contain a 4, because that would contradict your second criterion. I crossed them on the following grid:

The same way, two other cells cannot contain a 4:

The two remaining cells must contain a 4. Now for the 3s, lets focus on the one I highlighted here:

There is only one way to fill its neighboring cells fulfilling condition 2. One of the cells can be excluded by the following argument:

Once again, there is only one way to fill the rest of the grid:

I'd do the 1s, as it will be easier:

Finally, for the 2s, we fill the cells in the following way:

It is pleasant to observe that you don't have any choices! You end up with the following solution, which seems to be unique:


Nice ! I think "Computer Program" can be used to verify that there is no other Solution here !

Indeed, in a more general case, one could you backtracking algorithms!
